# How to resolve this : using a concatenated state is slower and will soon be deprecated use state_is_tuple=true. killed.?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to develop a model using recurrent neural networks with `MultiRNNCell` on Ubuntu 14.04 with tensorflow 0.9.0, but when I run my code on some input text, I get warning

> tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell.BasicsLSTMCell object at 0x7f56a4eaa610 using a concatenated state is slower and will soon be deprecated use state_is_tuple=true.

Then it gets killed.

Comment: Could you add more details about your code? `state_is_tuple=False` is deprecated. Could you try changing that to `True`?

Comment: i am trying to implement this using following article by Max Deutsch:  "How to write with artificial intelligence
An easy guide to Deep Writing without writing any code"  so i just downloaded that code and tried to run it.

Comment: i am unable to find "state_is_tuple=False" in the code so what should i do?